# TYPO3 user permissions: "read-only" Extension mananger and Templates module

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, typo3-4.5

---

Hi,
I'm looking for a way to set user permissions in the TYPO3 backend (Version 4.5.25 LTS in this special case) as follows:

- User should be able to see the modules "Extension Manager" and "Template"
- he is not allowed to edit the Templates, only read them (for evaluation or training purpose)
- he is not allowed to un/install extensions, languages etc, but read the extension list and the extensions informations provided in the list of installed extension.

Is this possible somehow? I know you can't restrict admin users like that. 
Is it possible to extend normal BE users like that? Or is there another way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible unless you create an extension for this that hooks into the access right evaluation.

For your usecase, I recommend to put all `TypoScript` templates into files and give the user read only access to the filesystem.

You can also ship all templates inside an extension, then you just need to share the `typo3conf/`folder.

Comment: This sounds like a reaonable way. I'm a fan of typoscript in files anyway. Sad thing is, that the former developer wrote it to the database.